# Data annotation validation vary by culture

Tags: c#, .net, validation, data-annotations

I want to validate zip code by data annotation, but in different country zip code has diffrent format.

In Poland correct is 12-345
In Russia correct is 123456

Have can I implement it in my code by Data Annotation, is it possible

```
[???]
public string ZipCode {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own custom validation. you can follow the following links for more information on how to create a custom validation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx

https://brunolm.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/using-data-annotations-to-validate-models/